# Matching Array to JavaScript Matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I’m wondering how to solve a matching/lookup problem and I “think” a multi-dimensional array is the solution.  In short, I want to match a list of comma separated SKUs stored as a cookie value against a finite list of SKUs with matching product names and print out the matched product names onto the page.  I’m not sure if this is the best way to do this, but with what I have so far I’m not clear how to properly breakup the comma separated strings from the cookie (right now it’s trying to match the entire cookie value), match them to the matrix (17 total rows) and then print out the Product Name.

```
<script>
var staticList = [
 [“1234”, “Chocolate Ice Cream”],
 [“1235”, “Peanut Butter Cookie”],
 [“6G2Y”, “Raspberry Jell-O”],
 [“YY23”, “Vanilla Wafers”]
];
var cookieSkus = [‘1235,YY23’];  // comma separated value from cookie

jQuery(function () {
 for (var i = 0; i < staticList.length; i++)  {
   if (cookieSkus.indexOf(staticList [i][0]) > -1) {
    jQuery('#pdisplay).append(staticList [i] [1] + '<br />');
   }
 }
});

</script>

<p id=”pdisplay”></p>
```

In this example, the paragraph "pdisplay" would contain:

Peanut Butter Cookie
Vanilla Wafers

Is there a way to correct what I have above or is there a better method of accomplishing what I’m trying to do?

Comment: is this correct [‘1235,YY23’] or it is like this ['1235','YY23'] instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might want to focus on the Cookie SKUs rather than the staticList. The reason for this is that the cookie may have a variable number, and may be as small as 0 elements. (After all, we don't need to list the items if there are no items).

This may be accomplished simply by converting the string to an array and then checking if the SKU is in the staticList. Unfortunately, since you are using a multidimensional array, this would require going through the staticList for each cookie sku. Using just this suggestion, here is a basic example and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FuzzicalLogic/r6SBC/):

**Rewrite: Accounting for the fact that staticList is an Array of Arrays**

```
jQuery(function() {
    var skus = cookieSkus[0].split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < skus.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < staticList.length; j++) {
            if (staticList[j][0] == skus[i]) {
                jQuery('#pdisplay').append(staticList[j][2] + '<br/>');
                break; // Will end inner if the item is found... Saves a lot of extra time.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit 2: Using an Object (A possibly better approach)**

According to the comments, you must support IE8. In this case, you might consider an Object instead of a multi-dimensional array. The reasons for this are as follows:

- An object is actually an associative array (with a few perks).
- You can directly check for property existence without having any nested arrays.
- Object property access is typically faster than looping through an array
- You can access object properties nearly exactly like accessing an array's elements.

When using an Object, the original version of my code may be used without modification. This is because the object's structure is simpler. Here is a fiddle for you: [option 2](http://jsfiddle.net/FuzzicalLogic/btf63/)

```
var staticList = {
    "1234": "Chocolate Ice Cream",
    "1235": "Peanut Butter Cookie",
    "6G2Y": "Raspberry Jell-O",
    "YY23": "Vanilla Wafers"
};

jQuery(function() {
    var skus = cookieSkus[0].split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < skus.length; i++) {
        if (staticList[skus[i]]) 
            jQuery('#pdisplay').append(staticList[skus[i]] + '<br/>');
    }
});
```

**Responding to your comment:**

The reason that the output matches what is desired is because unlike an array which has numerical indices, the object's indices are the actual skus. So, there is no `staticList[0]` if `staticList` is an object. Instead (in the context of the staticList object), 1234 = "Chocolate Ice Cream". So, an object definition basically goes as follows:

```
var objectName = {
    index1: value1,
    index2: value2,
    ...,
    ...
}
```

The index may be any primitive value (integer or string). The value may be any valid javascript value including a function or an inner object. Now, to get the value at a specific index, you may do either:

```
objectName.index1 (no quotes)
```

OR:

```
objectName["index1"] (quotes needed if the index is a string)
```

The result of either of those will be:

```
value1
```

It's as simple as that.

Comment: Fuzzical Logic - I cannot use Map becuase I have to support IE8.  I like the idea of using the cookie string instead of the larger matrix.  In the end, the function doesn't appear to work (I took care of the missing bracket in your example).  No errors, just doesn't match any of the values.  Also, in your example, wouldn't I do something like staticList[skus[i][1]] since I wanted the associated product name printed, not the matched string?

Comment: Understood about `map`, that's why it was added separately. Regarding the second question... You are correct. I didn't handle the name properly. Updating to account for this.

Comment: It occurs to me that I've buggered up this code. Taking some time to rewrite the answer entirely, rather than trying to quickly apply a typo fix. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Still not working for me.  I stripped out the IF statement and just printed both arrays to the page in the FOR loop to at least eliminate an issue with the arrays themselves.  It looks like the issue is the matching **(staticList[skus[i]][0])**.  Moving the bracket didn't seem to help ([skus[i][0]])

Comment: Alright. The answer has been rewritten. Please re-read completely as this is better thought out and another potential solution has been added.

Comment: I have run both versions correctly using Chrome debugger (copying your code and running it). I'll put it in two jsFiddles for you to see...

Comment: I like the second option and it appears to work, though I'm not sure I understand how it is capturing the second item in the object (e.g., Peanut Butter Cookie").  Just reading the coode, I don't understand why it isn't printing the entire line - 1235 : Peanut Butter Cookie

Comment: Sorry, was user error on my part - forget to copy jquery script to new test page.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
var cookieSkus = cookieSkus[0].split(',');

staticList.filter(function(cell){
     return  cookieSkus.some(function(val){return cell[0] === val; });   
 }).map(function(cell){
       jQuery('#pdisplay).append(cell[1] + '<br />');
    });
```

Disclaimer: provided based on the sample code provided above along with recent comments

Comment: OP specifically states that it is a comma separated value. This typically means string, not an array.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic this syntax [] suggests an array and it is surrounding the variable

Comment: Understood, but an array may be a single element keeping his statement entirely valid. If I were to improve your answer, I would account for the case that it is a single element array with the first element being a string, as well. This is also indicated by the actual code that he provides.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic I updated the solution based on these comments. Hope it helps

Comment: I need not mean for you to change your solution, as it is quite good if you are correct about the OPs post. I meant to imply that adding some clarification based on the code would improve your original answer.